# How do i impelement touch End on uislider above the scroll view: iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uislider, uitouch

In my app i have an UISlider on the scrollView,

I need to **move the slider to the next ciel/flor/round value when user removes finger from the slider,**

I implemented Touch delegate methods, begin & Cancel but these are not working on slider (may be due to the UIScroll view).

**Touch on uiscroll view NOT Working**

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

considering your situation i suggest to use **UITapGestureRecognizer**. 
First set up the TapGestureRecognizer on init.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognizer:)];
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

And then get the touches from following:

```
  - (void)tapRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
  { 
    CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:scrollView];
  }
```